# Setting events dynamically

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have this function that that I invoke `onload`:

```
function InitAll(){
   document.getElementById("div1").onmouseover = function(){Foo(event,this);};
   document.getElementById("div1").onmouseout  = function(){Foo(event,this);};
}

function Foo(e, handler){    
   document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML=e.type;
}
```

In IE it works and I get the right `e.type`, but in Firefox it does not:

> event is not defined

But if I set events statically,like:

```
<div id="div1" onmouseover="Foo(event,this);" onmouseout="Foo(event,this);" >
```

it works for both browsers.

What am I missing? some kind of closure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try taking the event object as the argument and replacing it with window.event if it is null.

```
function InitAll(){
   document.getElementById("div1").onmouseover = function(e){
      e = e || window.event;
      Foo(e,this);
   };
 ...
}
```

Though, honestly, I would look at using jQuery or some other framework for all of this.  There's no sense in reinventing the wheel in most cases.  I might do so when writing your own framework, but in most cases you'll save time and headaches with a framework.

Comment: @Andy E -- that's exactly what I was thinking, but I got stuck on the short circuit operator in C# (??) and I knew that wasn't right.  I'll update.

Comment: p.s. i don't want to use jquery right now because i want ot learn javascript  better, and like to implement everything using pure javascript.